# Creating a dataframe in pandas with one index column and the second column as a list of different sizes creating boxplot problems

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, boxplot, nested-lists

I am a beginner to Python. I am analyzing bus headways for each stop along a bus route. For each stop, I have a list of headways. The count of headway can be different for each stop. To visualize data, I want to plot boxplots on the same page so that you can observe how bus bunching occurs over the route. For this, I developed a code that reads bus data from a .csv file into a stop dictionary with the name as key and values as an object (I trace some other aspects of the stop but not included here for brevity). The trouble I am having is related to the boxplot. I thought pandas would provide some ease to do this. But, I had lots of trouble trying to set up a dataframe, because my dictionary includes objects. You may have other ideas. I simplified my code to a minimum so that you can still follow what I did. As a side note, I was trying to learn how to use classes while I was working on this analysis. That’s why you see bunch of classes in my code. In my full code, I deal with duplicate vehicles and outliers in their own methods.

```
stops={}
stopNamesA=[]
headwaysA=[]

class Data:
    def __init__(self):
         self.depart = 0
         self.vehicle = 0

class Stop:
    def __init__(self):
        self.vehicles = []
        self.departs = []
        self.headways=[]
        self.stopName =""
 def AddData(self, line):
        fields = line.split(",")
        self.stopName = fields[3]
        self.vehicles.append(fields[0])
        x = fields[4]
        self.departs.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(x[:-1], "%m/%d/%y %I:%M:%S %p"))
  def CalcHeadway(self):
        for i in range(len(self.departs)-1):
        dt = self.departs[i]
        dt2 = self.departs[i+1]
        self.headways.append(datetime.timedelta.total_seconds(dt2 - dt))

with open('data.csv','r') as f:
     for line in f:
         fields = line.split(",")
         sid = str(fields[3])
         if (fields[1] == 'X2' and fields[2] == 'WEST'):
             if sid in stops.keys():
                 s = stops[sid]
             else:
                 s = Stop()
                 stops[sid] = s
             s.AddData(line)

 for key, value in stops.items():
   value.CalcHeadway()
```

The data looks like the following (I truncated other parts again):

```
5401    X2  WEST    H ST NW + 7TH ST NW 10/3/16 7:58:48 AM
2835    X2  WEST    H ST NW + 7TH ST NW 10/3/16 8:16:49 AM
2460    X2  WEST    H ST NW + 7TH ST NW 10/3/16 8:20:12 AM
2460    X2  WEST    H ST NW + 7TH ST NW 10/3/16 8:20:38 AM
2460    X2  WEST    H ST NW + 7TH ST NW 10/3/16 8:20:57 AM
5404    X2  WEST    I ST + 14TH ST  10/3/16 8:01:55 AM
2835    X2  WEST    I ST + 14TH ST  10/3/16 8:24:01 AM
2853    X2  WEST    I ST + 14TH ST  10/3/16 9:27:07 AM
5404    X2  WEST    I ST + 14TH ST  10/3/16 9:45:43 AM
2835    X2  WEST    I ST + 14TH ST  10/3/16 9:57:31 AM
2831    X2  WEST    MINNESOTA AVE NE + BENNING RD NE    10/3/16 8:02:41 AM
2821    X2  WEST    MINNESOTA AVE NE + BENNING RD NE    10/3/16 8:17:42 AM
5420    X2  WEST    MINNESOTA AVE NE + BENNING RD NE    10/3/16 8:34:43 AM
2853    X2  WEST    MINNESOTA AVE NE + BENNING RD NE    10/3/16 8:44:14 AM
5401    X2  WEST    MINNESOTA AVE NE + BENNING RD NE    10/3/16 9:02:20 AM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, as the Error suggests, `'Series' object has no attribute 'boxplot'`. You can draw a boxplot from a `Series` by `Series.plot.box()`.
However since you want multiple boxes to appear, it makes sense to use a dataframe. So what you need is a `DataFrame` to plot your `boxplot` from.

If I understand your needs correctly, you'd need a `DataFrame` with 26 columns, one column per bus stop.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame()
df["I ST + 14TH ST"] = [1107.0, 1359.0, 1859.0, 1190.0, 1071.0, 904.0]
df["BENNING RD NE + 19TH ST NE"] =   [1132.0, 1503.0, 1448.0, 1344.0, 958.0, 771.0]
#......
df["H ST NW + 5TH ST NW"] = [1182.0, 1315.0, 1691.0, 1193.0, 956.0, 729.0]

df.boxplot(rot=45)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

It seems that in order to get a working dataframe out of the `stops` dictionary, one can do.

```
stops_for_drawing = {}
for key, val in stops.iteritems():
    stops_for_drawing.update({key: val.headways})
df = pd.DataFrame(stops_for_drawing)
```

Comment: @ ImportanceOfBeingErnestdf Thank you very much for your response. I tried the below code based on what you suggested. I get the error message IndexError: list index out of range when I box plot.= pd.DataFrame(index = stopNamesA)
for name, headway in zip(stopNamesA, headwaysA):
        df['name']=headway
df.boxplot()

Comment: @JohnV What exactly do you want to tell me with this piece of code? This is completely different from what I suggested in my answer. It is also completely wrong.

Comment: I am trying to make a for loop instead of typing each df[name]= ... like I think you did in your answer. Your graph is exactly what I want, but I have thousands of stops.

Comment: You can guess why I typed each column explicitely. Because you forced me to by not providing any data and by not stating anything about the structure of your initial data.

Comment: Would that be OK if I edit my question with my full code (to see data structures) and a link to the actual data?

Comment: It would be the worst of all solutions - read how to create a [MCVE]. Why can't you just give the original data shortened to the minimal dimension that you need to produce the problem? Let's say 3 bus stops, each with 5 data points.

Comment: @ ImportanceOfBeingErnest I edited my original question to follow your recommendations on the proper question technique. Thank you for holding my hand!

Comment: Still not ideal.. because you deleted the original question which was about plotting a dataframe. Could you provide a print out of `stops`? It seems to me that `stops` looks something like `{ "I ST + 14TH ST" : [1107.0, 1359.0, 1859.0 ...], etc.}` already in which case the dataframe would simply be created via `df = pd.DataFrame(stops)`.

Comment: This is the print out of stops. As expected, it is a dictionary with stop names as its keys, and a stop object as its values. {'H ST NW + 7TH ST NW': <__main__.Stop at 0x2289216cdd8>,
 'I ST + 14TH ST': <__main__.Stop at 0x2289216bda0>,
 'MINNESOTA AVE NE + BENNING RD NE': <__main__.Stop at 0x2289214d198>}

Comment: Edited the answer to include what I think you need. It's still more guessing, but what can I do without a runnable code?!

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much for your time and patience with me.

Comment: I'm glad it finally came out right. ;-) If this solves your problem, you can accept the answer.